# How to get a particular value from row in csv using python

Tags: python

I have a csv file with following data :

```
raj, male
rahul, male
reena, female
meena, female
```

Now I need to check the condition :

```
if row[1] =="Raj" and row[2] == "male"
print "Its a boy"
```

How I can do that in Python. I am pretty new with python. But no where I got a help to get a particular value from csv. I can print rows completely. but not one particular value. Please help

Comment: There is no `row[2]`

Comment: please dont consider it in a literal way. I want to compare the value row[1] and row[2] i put as an example. I am not sure how to do a comparison like that using python. Please help

Comment: Open the file with the csv module and index the elements from the row

Answer (score 0):

```
rows = []
for row in lines.split("\n"):
   rows.append([])
    rows[-1].append(row.split(", "))
```

Where lines is a string with the data

Then the variable rows will contain the data and you can do the query you had before

The split method splits the line into newlines and then by the commas

Answer (score 0):

```
input_file = "path to CSV"
file_1 = open(input_file, 'r')
lines = []
for line in file_1:
     lines.append(line)
for i in range(len(lines)):
     fields = []
     fields.append(lines[i].split(', '))
     if fields[0][1] == "male":
            print "It is a male."
file_1.close()
```